# apt-get update throws 404 errors

Tags: apt, updates, ppa

When trying to run `apt-get update` some some "404 not found" errors are showing up. The first of them is:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I had that problem the other night (although I was using Quantal), but then it downloaded fine a few minutes later. They're a small development project. They likely have a limit on the amount of bandwidth or connections they can allow at one time.

Comment: @chaskes The server is [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net). It's run by Canonical. A project's size only indirectly impacts the maximum bandwidth for a PPA. Even when an enormous amount of data are downloaded, a PPA won't flicker on and off as with some other sites. (Instead, Canonical contacts the PPA maintainer to figure out the situation. The PPA is kept accessible during this process. "While we don't enforce a strict limit on data transfer, we will get in touch with you if your data transfer looks unusually high." [Launchpad Help, "Packaging/PPA"](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA))

Comment: @eliah-kagen I did know it was Launchpad (I sent the project a couple of lines of code to fix a bug a while back) but didn't understand the bandwidth issues. I appreciate the info!

Answer (score 0):

that entry is incorrect in /etc/apt/sources.list.

i may be wrong, but i'm guessing that this entry in sources.list looks something like:

```
deb ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu/dists precise main sources<br/>
```

i'm not aware of any repo for sources but you can try taking the sources out of the listing and add this after that line.

```
deb-src ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu/dists precise main sources<br/>
```

...again, i wrote that line off the top of my head, but that list at the end of the line appears to be wrong.